# Can't add SOC machine

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to add a SOC machine to SOM server (distributed setup). From the server, I can see the service running. I have all the accounts properly setup. I may be still missing a super critical settings somewhere. This is the error that I am getting:

> Machine is not a valid server container. Machine
>    is not found.

My environment is Windows Server 2008 R2 (both SOM and SOC machines), ArcGIS Server 10.

I am curious if some had any idea what else to try. Is there a way to check if SOC is properly configured without using ArcCatalog or ArcGIS Server Manager.

Thanks
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you opened the necessary ports on the SOC machine? It needs to have:

```
135/TCP, 8099/TCP, 8399/TCP
```

If you're not sure, try telneting into those ports.

**Update per comment**

To telnet do a `telnet mySOCMachineNameorIP 135` from the SOM machine. This is an example of me checking to see whether gis.stackexchange.com has a port 80 open (web port):
[image]

If it's open you'll get a black screen with a blinking cursor (waiting for your command).
[image]

If it's closed, you'll get a "connecting to xxxx ... " message basically saying it's trying to connect and it cannot because the port is closed or some other connectivity issue. Below i'm trying to connect to gis.stackexchange.com on port 135 and of course it's closed.
[image]

Comment: Hi Capt., I have telnet installed but haven't used it before. Can you help me wih some sample commands. And thanks for the note above, will make sure to mark the answers. Thanks jay

Comment: @jay : please see the update to my answer.

Comment: So i can see that 135 is open but not the other two (8099, 8399). Do I must have these ports open. How Can I get these two other ports open, appreciate your feedback. Thanks Jay

Comment: I did another quick check with another functional SOC machine and it only has 135 open not the other two. May be it just needs port 135 open...intresting

Comment: please try [these steps](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/29168-cannot-add-SOC-server-machine-not-found) that *rtolapi* responded to.

Comment: actually, just for testing purposes i would shut down the firewall and see if that is the culprit. Because i think you're actually supposed to have the entire 1024-65535 range for DCOM to work because it chooses a port in that range randomly. (then turn the firewally back on of course).

Comment: Thanks Caption, turning firewall off resolved the problem and now I can connect. Thanks for helping me out. jay

Comment: Sure, no problem